# Pandas dataframe apply lambda based on inputs from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = df['IsPerson'].apply(lambda x: x if x==True else '')]

How can I apply lambda on the dataframe to make FullName = FirstName + ' ' + LastName? As far as I know lambda in dataframes has 1 input only? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `apply` here is not neccesary, only join columns together with `+`:

```
df['FullName'] = df.FirstName + ' ' + df.LastName
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['FullName'] = df.FirstName.str.cat(df.LastName, sep=' ')
```

Solution with `lambda` is possible, but slow:

```
df['FullName'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.FirstName + ' ' + x.LastName, axis=1)
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked :-) unfortunately I must use lambda as the problem I have is more complex (has if statement). I've posted that example for simplicity. A follow up question regarding speed...is lambda slow in general or in this specific case (when applied on dataframes)?

Comment: @ShadyMBA - It depends of formula. But generally is use `apply` it is slow, because loops under the hood.

Comment: So is there a way to do an if statement on a column without using lamda? The example you gave df['FullName'] = df.FirstName + ' ' + df.LastName is very elegant but I don't see a way to do it in case I need to use an if statement?

Comment: @ShadyMBA - then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659)

Comment: So I've applied your method and this works properly: 


df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = df.apply(lambda x: x['CleanName'] if x['IsPerson'] == True else '', axis = 1)  

However I've heard that List Comprehension is 50% faster so I was trying to translate the above code to the List Comprehension method but I'm getting an error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"...any suggestions to fix the error? Here's my attempted code:

df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = [x['CleanName'] if x['IsPerson'] == True else '' for x in df, axis = 1]  

Thanks!

Comment: @ShadyMBA - Can you test `df['GlobalName'] = np.where((df['GlobalName']=='') & (df['IsPerson']), df['CleanName'], '')` ?

Comment: Your code made the entire column = ''. But with a little tweak it worked as I wanted:  df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = np.where(df['IsPerson']==True, df['CleanName'], '') - basically apply the formula ONLY on empty rows...I think your code was overwriting existing cells. 

Your second solution is much more elegant than the lambda one and on top of that it is faster!! You're a genius. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadyMBA - You are welcome! Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)

Comment: 3 solutions:
`%timeit df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = df.apply(lambda x: x['CleanName'] if x['IsPerson'] == True else '', axis = 1)`  

`%timeit df['GlobalName'][df['GlobalName']==''] = np.where(df['IsPerson']==True, df['CleanName'], '')`  

`%timeit df['GlobalName'] = np.where((df['IsPerson']==True) & (df['GlobalName']==''), df['CleanName'], df['GlobalName'])`  


39.6 ms
40.6 ms  
1.21 ms  

The 3rd solution is super fast compared to the other 2.